# How to remove <ul> elements if they dont have <li> elements

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and jQuery, I am currently using the bootstrap navigation bar (multiple submenus). I have a PHP script that outputs the navigation in ul and li elements. There are some ul elements that do not have li elements in it (some sub menu do not have further sub menu). Therefore the ul that does not have li, Bootstrap shows it as an empty menu which I dont want.

Anyway of finding if any of the ul is empty and therefore change the CSS to display: none? i have tried the following but doesn't work:

```
$( "ul" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).html()==""){
        $(this).css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$( "ul" ).not(':has(li)').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WMjpc/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this thing drove me crazy

Answer (score 3):

Try [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector:

```
$( "ul:empty" ).hide();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yGxj2/
But it has some restriction:

> One important thing to note with :empty (and :parent) is that child
>   elements include text nodes.

It means if you have spaces in tag's `innerHTML` - `:empty` will not work on this tag..

Comment: that is the problem, because it heavily depends on the markup structure